# CakePHP3 "Helper not found" error in plugin

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have created a helper "SideNavbarHelper.php" in {appname}/plugins/UsefulHelpers/src/View/Helper, 
and I am trying to set helper in beforeRender in AppController, but I got following error.

> Error: UsefulHelpers.SideNavbarHelper could not be found.

beforeRender in AppController.php

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeRender($event);
    $this->helpers["Navbar"]  =  ["className"=>"UsefulHelpers.SideNavbar"];
}
```

SideNavbarHelper.php

```
namespace UsefulHelpers\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\Helper;
class SideNavbarHelper extends Helper {    
    public $helpers = ["Html"];
    public function defaultNavbar() {
        //some code here...
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that the plugin in loaded in bootstrap.php.
Why am I getting the error?

Comment: have you loaded the plugin?

Comment: Yes, I loaded it in bootstrap.php. I confirmed it is correctly loaded because if I change the plugin name which does not exists, then the error message changes.

Comment: set `namespace` & `use`??

Comment: yes. Actually the answer below solved my problem. Anyways, thank you very much.

Comment: OP, did it work for you? I've been trying to make my Helper work since a week ago, and I was starting to suspect that `cakephp-3.0` had some bug.

Comment: @GuiImamura What I did was just to modify composer.json so that composer would generates autoloader files which include my plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure there is an autoloader setup for your plugin classes. Please refer this section in the documentation:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes